# How to play asf stream using vitamio?

Tags: android, vitamio

I am using vitamio library to play online audo stream, but this cannot play asf stream.

```
    mPlayer=new mPlayer(this);

        try {
            mPlayer.setDataSource(path);
            //mPlayer.prepareAsync(); // prepare async to not block
            // main
                mPlayer.prepare();
            mPlayer.start();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mPlayer is onStartCommand error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mPlayer is onStartCommand error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "mPlayer is onStartCommand error");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Plz help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vitamio support asf stream. What's wrong with you? error log?

Comment: Hey John, please tell me how you have solved, playing asf in android..please help me